# why bootstrap grid column are not properly divide in angular 4?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

**I have the following html code**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 custom">
      div1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 custom">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make grid of 2 columns generally it could come as 2 column grid in bootstrap but when i am trying to do it in angular 4 inside a component ,then it is stacking width is not properly handling  I guess ,can you confirm what is issue since its just a basic and simple html code 
additional css code i applied is following

```
.custom{
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: grey;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a large screen? Because you've told bootstrap to stack the divs vertically unless your window width is large enough (at least 1200px).

Comment: Hi my window screen is more than 1200 its around 1365 but still divs are vertically stacked ,but in default behavior it should have been horizontally in one row.please note that i tried to see the width if less percent then it places horizontally ,what could be the reason.

Comment: It's your margin. It makes each div too large to fin in its column. If you want the contents of each cell to have an additional margin, then embed a div inside the .col-lg-6: http://run.plnkr.co/preview/cj9vijkqy00053i5sjvhhx8gb/

Comment: Thanks JB its working ,saved my time